# Finding the pixel value inside a threshold python

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, contour

so I'm just asking if anyone knows how to find the value of the pixels insides the contour because I'm doing this project to see if any of the mangoes have damages and what I'm aiming for is to see if any pixel inside the contour exceed 100. Much Help is needed. Thank you.

This is my current code:

```
import cv2

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
img = cv2.imread('final.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
edges = cv2.Canny(img, 180,255)

plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(img)
plt.title('Original Gray Scale Image')
plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(edges)
plt.title('Edge Image')



plt.show()
```

[The output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21HSb.png)
[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czjna.jpg)

Comment: Please pay attention to the format of the question. Please improve it too.

Comment: Hi @Ginz I worked in a project to detect black spots or 'anthracnose' in mangoes using image processing. Here is my result https://imgur.com/a/h8oNhSF here my video https://youtu.be/qP7H-IGlOJw?t=325 'in spanish' I did a proposed method, you can contact me creatorpart@gmail.com or aibanezf@crece.uss.edu.pe

Comment: What is it that you want exactly? You can threshold on color or background using cv2.inrange(). Then get the contour. Then use the filled contour to make a mask. Then use the mask the blank out the background.

Comment: @fmw42 hi thank you for responding, I want to store the value of the of any pixel inside the contour.

Comment: Pixels have 3 colors. What do you mean by exceeds 100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "greater than 100", since your image is color and so has 3 values: B, G, R.  But here is how to print the B,G,R values where the intensity is larger than some threshold in Python/OpenCV. I have also marked in red on the intensity image where the values are larger than some threshold, which you can change to 100 if you want. I used 190 to keep the list shorter.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# set intensity threshold
thresh = 190

# read image
img = cv2.imread('green_region.jpg')

# convert img to grayscale intensity
intensity = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# get img where intensity is larger than thresh
data = img[intensity>thresh]

# get coordinates where intensity is larger than thresh
coords = np.argwhere(intensity>thresh)

# print coordinates x,y vs bgr color
for (y,x),(b,g,r)in zip(coords,data):
    print(x, y, ": ", b, g, r)

# draw red pixels on intensity image where larger than thresh
result = intensity.copy()
result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
result[intensity>thresh] = (0,0,255)

# save result
cv2.imwrite('green_region_190.jpg', result)

# show thresh and result    
cv2.imshow("intensity", intensity)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Intensity with red for pixels larger than 190:

[image]

Pixel colors where intensity larger than 190:

```
x y :  b g r

574 367 :  164 212 160
539 382 :  170 214 153
538 383 :  170 214 153
539 383 :  170 214 153
539 384 :  173 214 153
538 385 :  173 214 152
539 385 :  173 214 153
561 385 :  172 210 160
538 386 :  173 214 152
539 386 :  173 214 153
538 387 :  173 214 152
538 388 :  173 214 152
536 392 :  173 214 152
536 393 :  173 214 152
543 398 :  173 214 153
542 399 :  173 214 153
543 399 :  174 215 154
544 399 :  175 214 158
545 399 :  174 213 157
442 400 :  157 213 160
535 400 :  175 215 150
552 400 :  177 212 155
535 401 :  176 216 151
535 402 :  177 217 152
536 402 :  175 214 152
534 403 :  175 215 150
535 403 :  178 218 153
536 403 :  175 214 152
537 403 :  175 214 152
534 404 :  176 216 151
535 404 :  178 218 153
536 404 :  175 214 152
537 404 :  175 214 152
534 405 :  176 216 151
535 405 :  178 218 153
536 405 :  175 214 152
534 406 :  176 216 151
535 406 :  177 217 152
534 407 :  175 215 150
535 407 :  177 217 152
532 408 :  175 215 150
533 408 :  175 215 150
534 408 :  176 216 151
535 408 :  176 216 151
532 409 :  175 215 150
533 409 :  175 215 150
534 409 :  176 216 151
535 409 :  176 216 151
532 410 :  175 215 150
533 410 :  175 215 150
534 410 :  176 216 151
535 410 :  176 216 151
532 411 :  175 215 150
533 411 :  175 215 150
534 411 :  176 216 151
535 411 :  176 216 151
532 412 :  175 215 150
533 412 :  175 215 150
534 412 :  176 216 151
535 412 :  176 216 151
532 413 :  175 215 150
533 413 :  175 215 150
534 413 :  176 216 151
535 413 :  176 216 151
532 414 :  175 215 150
533 414 :  175 215 150
534 414 :  176 216 151
535 414 :  176 216 151
536 414 :  175 214 152
537 414 :  175 214 152
538 414 :  173 214 152
455 415 :  154 213 162
525 415 :  173 217 148
526 415 :  174 218 149
527 415 :  174 218 149
532 415 :  175 215 150
533 415 :  175 215 150
534 415 :  176 216 151
535 415 :  176 216 151
536 415 :  176 215 153
537 415 :  176 215 153
538 415 :  174 215 153
539 415 :  173 214 152
540 415 :  173 214 152
529 416 :  175 213 153
530 416 :  175 213 153
531 416 :  175 213 153
532 416 :  175 213 153
533 416 :  175 213 153
536 416 :  175 213 153
537 416 :  175 213 153
527 417 :  177 214 150
529 417 :  175 213 153
530 417 :  175 213 153
531 417 :  175 213 153
532 417 :  175 213 153
533 417 :  175 213 153
536 417 :  175 213 153
537 417 :  175 213 153
538 417 :  175 213 153
526 418 :  178 216 150
527 418 :  179 216 152
528 418 :  175 213 153
529 418 :  175 213 153
530 418 :  175 213 153
531 418 :  175 213 153
532 418 :  175 213 153
533 418 :  175 213 153
536 418 :  176 214 154
537 418 :  175 213 153
538 418 :  175 213 153
539 418 :  175 213 153
526 419 :  177 215 149
527 419 :  178 215 151
528 419 :  175 213 153
529 419 :  175 213 153
530 419 :  175 213 153
531 419 :  175 213 153
532 419 :  175 213 153
533 419 :  175 213 153
534 419 :  175 213 153
535 419 :  175 213 153
536 419 :  176 214 154
537 419 :  176 214 154
538 419 :  175 213 153
539 419 :  175 213 153
528 420 :  176 214 154
529 420 :  176 214 154
530 420 :  176 214 154
531 420 :  176 214 154
532 420 :  176 214 154
533 420 :  176 214 154
534 420 :  175 213 153
535 420 :  175 213 153
536 420 :  176 214 154
537 420 :  176 214 154
538 420 :  176 214 154
539 420 :  175 213 153
528 421 :  176 214 154
529 421 :  176 214 154
530 421 :  177 215 155
531 421 :  177 215 155
532 421 :  177 215 155
533 421 :  177 215 155
534 421 :  176 214 154
535 421 :  176 214 154
536 421 :  177 215 155
537 421 :  177 215 155
538 421 :  176 214 154
539 421 :  175 213 153
528 422 :  176 215 153
529 422 :  177 216 154
530 422 :  178 217 155
531 422 :  178 217 155
532 422 :  178 217 155
533 422 :  178 217 155
534 422 :  177 216 154
535 422 :  176 215 153
536 422 :  178 217 155
537 422 :  178 217 155
538 422 :  177 216 154
539 422 :  176 215 153
540 422 :  175 214 152
528 423 :  176 215 153
529 423 :  177 216 154
530 423 :  178 217 155
531 423 :  179 218 156
532 423 :  179 218 156
533 423 :  178 217 155
534 423 :  177 216 154
535 423 :  176 215 153
536 423 :  179 218 156
537 423 :  178 217 155
538 423 :  178 217 155
539 423 :  177 216 154
540 423 :  176 215 153
544 423 :  177 214 150
529 424 :  175 214 152
530 424 :  178 217 155
531 424 :  178 217 155
532 424 :  178 217 155
533 424 :  177 216 154
534 424 :  177 216 154
535 424 :  177 216 154
536 424 :  177 216 154
537 424 :  177 216 154
538 424 :  176 215 153
539 424 :  175 214 152
540 424 :  175 214 152
528 425 :  175 214 152
529 425 :  177 216 154
530 425 :  178 217 155
531 425 :  179 218 156
532 425 :  177 216 154
533 425 :  176 215 153
534 425 :  176 215 153
535 425 :  177 216 154
536 425 :  176 215 153
537 425 :  176 215 153
538 425 :  175 214 152
539 425 :  175 214 152
525 426 :  177 215 149
528 426 :  176 215 153
529 426 :  178 217 155
530 426 :  179 218 156
531 426 :  178 217 155
532 426 :  176 215 153
533 426 :  175 214 152
534 426 :  175 214 152
535 426 :  175 214 152
536 426 :  175 214 152
537 426 :  175 214 152
524 427 :  177 215 149
525 427 :  178 216 150
526 427 :  177 215 149
528 427 :  177 217 152
529 427 :  178 218 153
530 427 :  178 218 153
531 427 :  177 217 152
504 428 :  168 217 149
524 428 :  177 215 149
525 428 :  178 216 150
526 428 :  178 216 150
528 428 :  176 216 151
529 428 :  176 216 151
530 428 :  176 216 151
504 429 :  168 217 149
510 429 :  172 218 146
511 429 :  172 218 146
524 429 :  177 215 149
525 429 :  178 216 150
526 429 :  177 215 149
528 429 :  175 215 150
529 429 :  175 215 150
530 429 :  175 215 150
496 430 :  164 215 155
497 430 :  164 215 155
510 430 :  172 218 146
511 430 :  172 218 146
524 430 :  177 215 149
525 430 :  178 216 150
526 430 :  177 215 149
528 430 :  175 215 150
529 430 :  175 215 150
496 431 :  165 216 156
497 431 :  164 215 155
510 431 :  172 218 146
511 431 :  172 218 146
525 431 :  177 215 149
528 431 :  175 215 150
529 431 :  175 215 150
530 431 :  175 215 150
499 432 :  166 216 152
500 432 :  167 217 153
501 432 :  168 215 152
527 432 :  177 215 149
528 432 :  175 214 152
534 432 :  175 215 150
535 432 :  176 216 151
499 433 :  167 217 153
500 433 :  167 217 153
501 433 :  168 215 152
535 433 :  175 215 150
497 434 :  166 215 153
498 434 :  167 217 153
499 434 :  168 218 154
500 434 :  167 217 153
501 434 :  168 215 152
496 435 :  167 216 154
497 435 :  167 217 153
498 435 :  168 218 154
499 435 :  168 218 154
500 435 :  167 217 153
496 436 :  167 217 153
497 436 :  167 217 153
498 436 :  167 217 153
499 436 :  166 216 152
496 437 :  166 216 152
496 440 :  166 217 150
512 440 :  175 216 148
519 440 :  178 216 150
523 440 :  177 215 149
524 440 :  178 216 150
525 440 :  178 216 150
526 440 :  178 216 150
527 440 :  178 216 150
519 441 :  177 215 149
523 441 :  177 215 149
524 441 :  178 216 150
525 441 :  178 216 150
526 441 :  177 215 149
527 441 :  177 215 149
523 442 :  177 215 149
524 442 :  177 215 149
525 442 :  177 215 149
512 447 :  176 217 149
513 447 :  175 216 148
482 448 :  163 215 155
483 448 :  165 216 156
520 448 :  177 218 150
521 448 :  176 217 149
512 449 :  175 216 148
513 449 :  175 216 148
520 449 :  176 217 149
513 450 :  175 216 148
477 454 :  159 216 155
520 454 :  176 217 149
477 455 :  159 216 155
514 455 :  175 216 148
515 455 :  176 217 149
516 455 :  176 217 149
517 455 :  175 216 148
518 455 :  175 216 148
519 455 :  175 216 148
520 455 :  177 218 150
521 455 :  176 217 149
475 456 :  161 218 157
476 456 :  162 219 158
477 456 :  160 217 156
512 456 :  175 216 148
513 456 :  175 216 148
514 456 :  176 217 149
515 456 :  177 218 150
516 456 :  178 219 151
517 456 :  177 218 150
518 456 :  177 218 150
519 456 :  177 218 150
520 456 :  178 219 151
521 456 :  178 219 151
522 456 :  178 219 151
523 456 :  177 218 150
474 457 :  159 216 155
475 457 :  160 217 156
476 457 :  160 217 156
513 457 :  175 216 148
514 457 :  176 217 149
515 457 :  177 218 150
516 457 :  177 218 150
517 457 :  177 218 150
518 457 :  177 218 150
519 457 :  176 217 149
520 457 :  177 218 150
521 457 :  177 218 150
522 457 :  177 218 150
523 457 :  175 216 148
514 458 :  175 216 148
515 458 :  176 217 149
516 458 :  176 217 149
517 458 :  176 217 149
518 458 :  176 217 149
519 458 :  176 217 149
520 458 :  175 216 148
521 458 :  175 216 148
522 458 :  175 216 148
514 459 :  175 216 148
515 459 :  175 216 148
516 459 :  176 217 149
517 459 :  176 217 149
518 459 :  175 216 148
519 459 :  175 216 148
515 460 :  175 216 148
516 460 :  175 216 148
517 460 :  175 216 148
444 488 :  150 215 160
444 489 :  151 216 161
444 490 :  151 216 161
```

Comment: dude thanks this is the one I'm saying about sorry for confusing you, Thank you..